# Is there a way to have Resharper fix everything on the file (with the first option)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, resharper

I am doing a lot of refactorings with Resharper.

It would be really nice if there was a way to tell Resharper to fix everthing it finds as it sees fit.

Anyone know a way to do that?

Comment: Wouldn't this take into account the level of severity you've assigned to various fixables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Code Cleanup command (Ctrl + Alt + F) and choose a cleanup profile. If you want to do it with one command, use (Ctrl + Shift + Alt + F) and it will allow you to select a default cleanup profile, and do it automatically from that point on. (until you change it again through the options menu)

Comment: BTW, this solution doesn't do exactly what you're asking for, but is the closest option I can think of.

Comment: That was the closest I could get too.  Ah, well, I will have to do it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible.